# How to display image from a js file in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new at programming and very new to React. I'm trying to display an image that comes from a data.js file. I'm getting datas, but not the image. My console.log displays the image path correctly. I know my path is ok because I've tried to import the image and it works fine.

I've tried to create a .env file to mention NODE_PATH=src so I can have absolute path, but that doesn't work either, and I think this a deprecated way to handle absolute path. 
I've also tried to put some random url image from google, but it wouldn't work either. That makes me think my problem is not about path.

```
// My app.js file 

import React from 'react';
import GetImages from './components/ImagesTest/getImages';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="header">Local Storage</h1>
      <GetImages/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


// My class file 
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Data from './data';


class GetImages extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Data: Data
        };
    }

    render(){
        const {Data} = this.state;

        return(
            <div>
            {
                 Data.map(data=>(

                     <div>
                        { console.log(data.src) }
                        <img src= {data.src} alt = {data.alt}></img>
                        <p>{data.note}</p>
                        <p>{data.w}</p>
                        <p>{data.h}</p>
                     </div>

                ))
            }

            </div>
        )    
    }
}

export default GetImages;


// My data.js file

const pictures = [
    {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "the_cats",
        "place": "",
        "note": "This a cat picture",
        "datePhoto": "2018",
        "w": "5312",
        "h": "2988",
        "src": "/../cat1.jpg",
        "alt" : "cat image",
        "lblDate": "Date : ",
        "lblPlace": "Place : ",
        "lblNote": "Note : "
    }
]

export default pictures;
```

Sorry if that question is to easy.. Any help would be great 'cause I'm kind of lost here. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: I suspect you didn't enable the file loader: check this link https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images

Comment: Thanks for your answer !! You're right I didn't do it. Am  i supposed to create a webpack.config.js file ? Because I don't have any in my react projects, which surprised me because it was created automatically when I did some Symfony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this [webpack template](https://github.com/fable-compiler/webpack-config-template/blob/master/webpack.config.js)  as a starter.

The file-load part, https://blog.cloudboost.io/webpack-for-beginners-part-1-bf8d65e58ecf explains the `filer-loader` to serve image file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that !

Comment: So I followed the steps and installed file-loader. I'm able to add a css file and adding image url. It works fine, but I still can't render images coming from my data.js file. I've put my image folder into the public one so that it can go to the build folder when I run npm build. But still doesn't render. Any idea why ?

Comment: Ok, so I changed the path and it finally renders ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: I did accept it. But I'm knew at stackoverflow and I had a message telling me it has been took into account for when I have more points..